# How to model Peer Row in a Database

Tags: sql, database-design, constraints

I'm modeling a Peer 2 Peer Relation in a Database(H2, specifically but for this question, any RDBMS should do.)

Say, I have an Equipment Table

```
CREATE TABLE  EQUIPMENTS (
    ID LONG PRIMARY KEY,
    VENDOR VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    MODEL VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PORT VARCHAR(50),
    peer_equipment_id LONG REFERENCES EQUIPMENTS(ID)
);
```

Now, suppose I have to insert 2 records into this table like below :

```
insert into EQUIPMENTS
    (ID, VENDOR, MODEL, PORT,  peer_equipment_id)
       VALUES (1,  'vendor1', 'model1', 'port3',  2);
```

The DB gives Referential Integrity constraint violation error since equipments row with id = 2 is not already in the DB.

How should one model this relationship and still keep referential integrity ?

Any insight helps. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`insert`, `insert`, `update`:

```
insert into EQUIPMENTS (ID, VENDOR, MODEL, PORT,  peer_equipment_id)
    VALUES (1,  'vendor1', 'model1', 'port3',  NULL);

insert into EQUIPMENTS (ID, VENDOR, MODEL, PORT,  peer_equipment_id)
    VALUES (2,  'vendor2', 'model2', 'port3',  NULL);

update EQUIPMENTS
    set peer_equipment_id = 2
    where id = 1;
```